# Using LinkedList in Dictionary C#? And how to implement it's operations?

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a dictionary where value is a LinkedList. Below is a scenario:

```
public class TransactionTest
{
    private Dictionary<string, LinkedListNode<int>> stocks = new Dictionary<string, LinkedListNode<int>>();

    public TransactionTest()
    {
    }

    public void BuyTransaction(string ticker, int amount) {

        if (!stocks.ContainsKey(ticker))
        {

            LinkedList<int> linkedLists = new LinkedList<int>();
            stocks.Add(ticker, linkedLists.AddFirst(amount));
        }

        else if (stocks.ContainsKey(ticker)) {
            LinkedList<int> linkedLists = new LinkedList<int>();

            stocks[ticker] = linkedLists.AddLast(amount);
        }
            
    }

    public void toStringImpl() {
        Console.WriteLine(stocks.ToString());
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error below:

```
TransactionTest test = new TransactionTest();
test.BuyTransaction("AAPL", 100);

 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode`1[System.Int32]]
```

I'm not sure how to go about this - how can I do the following:

1. Create a new LinkedList for a new Key when it doesn't exist in the dictionary
2. If key exists, add amount at it's values' LinkedList

Thanks!

Comment: `I'm getting an error` - What's the error?

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode`1[System.Int32]]

Comment: that's not an error, that's just the name of a type. There should be an error message along with it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is because you use bare `int` value which cannot be converted into `LinkedList` implicitly. Instead, you should instance a new object as `new LinkedListNode<int>(100);`.

As you see its `Value` property holds the value which is `100`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So I can add the below?

Comment: if (!stocks.ContainsKey(ticker))
            {

                LinkedListNode<int> node = new LinkedListNode<int>(amount);
                stocks.Add(ticker, node);
            }

Comment: @Y.V yes, I haven’t analyzed your code logically but grammatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your dictionary initialization code. You have written-
`private Dictionary<string, LinkedListNode<int>> stocks = new Dictionary<string, LinkedListNode<int>>();`

you need to be using `LinkedList<int>` instead of `LinkedListNode<int>` and you can continue doing an operation like-

```
LinkedList<int> linkedLists = new LinkedList<int>();
stocks.Add(ticker, linkedLists.AddFirst(amount));
```

which will add a LinkedList as a value to your dictionary as per your requirement.

Comment: Got it! And the second part can just be:

Comment: else if (stocks.ContainsKey(ticker)) {
                stocks[ticker].AddLast(amount);
                
             }

Comment: it should be ` else if (stocksContainsKey(ticker)) { stocks[ticker] = stocks[ticker].AddLast(amount); }`